# How to make exe file for python file.?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, exe

I'm making an GUI application using Tkinter, but I'm not able to run this file on other operating systems. How can I do this?

Python version is 3.5.2, and working on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

Install PyInstaller from PyPI:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to your program’s directory and run:

```
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called `dist`.

Comment: --onefile tag is needed for packaging into a single executable. pyinstaller --onefile yourprogram.py

Comment: pyinstaller -F yourprogram.py

Comment: Did you test `pyinstaller --onefile` vs `py2exe` performance ? My  opinion `--onefile` isn't good choice !